# What open-source tool you will suggest for deployment and management of operating systems?

Tags: open-source, network-monitor, system-monitor, operating-system, network-administration

We need a free and open-source deployment and management tool which should have following features:

- Tool can manage both windows and linux systems.
- Automatic OS installation.
- Automatic software distribution and patch management.
- Hardware and software inventories.

We have checked multiple tools eg. OpenGnSys, opsi etc. but there was some problems like 1. Only suitable for windows. 2. Detailed documentation is not provided 3. Not FOSS.

What will you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend the [Hashicorp](https://www.hashicorp.com/) ecosystem of [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com), [Packer](https://www.packer.io), etc. they let you specify and provision your operating system, installed software, settings, etc., in a version controllable manner using json scripts.

- Cross Platform
- Multiple targets
- Free, gratis & [Open Source](https://github.com/hashicorp) *with the exception of one or two of the offerings but you can 100% work with the FOSS tools.*

Comment: do i need to install them (vagrant, packer, serf, vault etc) one-by-one?

Comment: @Tejas - yes but just the bits that you need, the instructions are helpful __apart from__ not mentioning the need to do a `vagrant box add` _target_ __before__ the first `vagrant init` for a given target the first time that you use a given target on that machine.